# cannot use forkJoin with redux-observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm a little confused trying to get rxjs to play nice here.

I can do single API requests just fine, e.g.

```
const documentFetchEpic: Epic<TRootAction, TRootAction, TRootState> = (action$, store) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(documentActions.fetch)),
    withLatestFrom(store),
    switchMap(([action, state]) =>
      merge(
        of(sharedActions.setLoading(true)),
        ApiUtils.documents.fetch(action.payload).pipe(
          mergeMap(response => [
            sharedActions.setLoading(false),
            documentActions.fetchSuccess({
              name: action.payload,
              data: response,
            }),
          ]),
          catchError(err => of(sharedActions.setError(err), sharedActions.setLoading(false)))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

works as expected.

The issue is when I try fetch multiple items at a time via `forkJoin`. I'm not quite sure what to make of this.

```
const DocumentTypes = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const fetchAll = () =>
    forkJoin<{ name: TDocumentTypes; data: DocumentRes }>(
      ...DocumentTypes.map(documentType =>
        ApiUtils.documents.fetch(documentType).pipe(map(response => ({ name: documentType, data: response.data })))
      )
    )

const documentFetchAllEpic: Epic<TApiActions, TApiActions, TApiState> = (action$, store) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(documentActions.fetchAll)),
    withLatestFrom(store),
    switchMap(([action, state]) =>
      merge(
        of(sharedActions.setLoading(true)),
        fetchAll().pipe(
          mergeMap(responses => [
            sharedActions.setLoading(false),
            responses.map(response => {
              documentActions.fetchSuccess({
                name: response.name,
                data: response.data,
              });
            }),
          ]),
          catchError(err => of(sharedActions.setError(err), sharedActions.setLoading(false)))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

This fails to compile, with the following error:

```
Type 'void[]' is missing the following properties from type 'PayloadAction<"@@api/shared/SET_LOADING", Error>': type, payloadts(2322)
```

I don't have a great understanding of rx.js so I'm guessing my issue lies there. I want to wrap up all of the documentFetch Observables into a `forkJoin` and then treat it like I did prior.

Comment: What line throws this error?

Comment: I'm not sure, but commenting out `responses.map(....)` removes the issue

Comment: but that's also where I'm calling actions with the results, so I do need that :/

Answer (score 0):

Ah. i didn't understand mergeMap. The issue was that my `responses.map(...)` was returning `Void[]`

so the corrected block is

```
          mergeMap(responses => [
            sharedActions.setLoading(false),
            ...responses.map(response =>
              documentActions.fetchSuccess({
                name: response.name,
                data: response.data,
              })
            ),
          ]),
```